# Rest call and database Save using C# Async Await not working

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I have case there i will make rest call and based on response i will save it into database.

```
private async Task<bool> ProcessParallal<T>(IList<T> t,PropertyInfo pi, string name, int Id)
{
    string mainId = null,intermediateId = null;

    var tasks = t.Select(async item =>
    {
        var response = await CallRestApi(item,(long)(pi.GetValue(item)),name,id);

        //Saving Rsult based on RestAPi result
        // Requiremnt is wait until databse operation finishes
        await this.SaveToTable(response.id,name,id));

    });
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return await Task.FromResult(false);
}

private async Task<string> SaveToTable(int responseId,name,id)
{
    //Save details in Audit Table 
    _iDataAccess.AuditSave(responseId,name,id);
    return await Task.FromResult("Success");
}

public async Task<ResponseResult> CallRestApi<T>(T itemObj,id,name)
{
    //Fetching From DB
    var info = await fetchDetailsFromDB(id, name);
   //Rest Api Call
   return await CreateNewEntryByRestCall<T>(itemObj,info.name);
}
```

But ProcessParallal doesnot wait until Database operation Finishes (ie SaveToTable method) .ProcessParallal method returns before database operation completes.

Can anyone point out issue with this code ..

Comment: What happens when you put a .ToList() on the end of the Select?
i.e. var tasks = t.Select(async item => ...).ToList();

Comment: @peinearydevelopment ..Is it make any difference.. I will test ..

Comment: Not able to reproduce this issue. Are you sure ProcessParallal returns before  SaveToTable method is completed?..  Can you verify again, may be you can put some logs.

Comment: Yes..its behaves like that..stuck on this..

Comment: _.ProcessParallal method returns before database operation completes_ - this is by design of `async-await` approach. When execution "hit" a line with `await` and if returned instance of `Task` is not complete - execution return to the caller of `ProcessParallal` method. When task is complete execution continue from await line. In your case this hapenned when execution "hit" line `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` I think you need describe more specifically your problem and tell us what you mean by "_doesnot wait until Database operation Finishes_" and how you check that it doesn't wait it

Comment: How are you calling `ProcessParallel()`?  Also you do not need to do this: `return await Task.FromResult(false)`; just `return false` instead.

Comment: Also, is `_iDataAccess.AuditSave()` a sync or async method?  You can edit the answer to show its declaration.

Comment: (BTW I of course meant edit the question...)

Comment: AuditSave is synchronous method

Comment: Is it possible `IList<T> t` is empty?  Are you sure it's getting to the call to `CallRestApi()`, for instance?  Also if `_iDataAccess.AuditSave()` is sync, there is no point making `SaveToTable()` async like that; just leave it as a void method that calls `_iDataAccess.AuditSave()` (or call it directly in your lambda).  You still need to show us how you call `ProcessParallel()`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question properly with waiting on the ProcessParallal method, your asynchronous call

> ```
> private async Task<bool> ProcessParallal<T>(IList<T> t,PropertyInfo pi, string name, int Id)
> ```

should then be changed to be a synchronous call:

```
private bool ProcessParallal<T>(IList<T> t,PropertyInfo pi, string name, int Id)
```